# ActionSupport on selectRadio not Calling Setter Method and also not rerendering outputPanel

Tags: actionsupport, selectradio

I came across similar posts but my solution is not working at all. I have to show two options with radio buttons and render different outputpanel for each selection. Code Snippet is below. 
Initailly ExistingEntity value present hence  'availSection' section is displayed by default. When i click 'Create New Parent Entity' option, the correponding block is rendering.Pbm is when i switch back to 'Select Existing Parent Entities'
then i dont see either actionSuport or setter are being invoked. Please advise me how to make it work.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection id="choice" title="Choice" collapsible="false" columns="1">
 <apex:selectRadio value="{!selectedOption}">
 <apex:selectOption itemValue="ExistingEntity" itemLabel="Select Existing Parent Entities"/>
 <apex:selectOption itemValue="NewEntity" itemLabel="Create New Parent Entity"/>
 <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="newSection,availSection"/>
 </apex:selectRadio>
 </apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:outputPanel id="availSection">
<apex:outputPanel id="innerSec">
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Available Records" collapsible="false" columns="1" rendered="{!IF(selectedOption == 'ExistingEntity', true, false)}">
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>

<apex:outputPanel id="newSection">
 <apex:outputPanel id="newSectionInner">
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Create New Entity" collapsible="false" columns="2" rendered="{!IF(selectedOption == 'NewEntity', true, false)}">
<apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Can you include your code?  Both the VF page and the controller/extension.

Comment: Page:<apex:pageBlockSection id="choice" title="Choice" collapsible="false" columns="1">
<apex:selectRadio value="{!selectedOption}">
<apex:selectOption itemValue="ExistingEntity" itemLabel=" Existing  Entities" itemDisabled="{!IF(showParentEntitieInfo.size == 0, true, false)}"/>
           <apex:selectOption itemValue="NewEntity" itemLabel="Create New Entity"/>
  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="newSection,availSection"/>
          </apex:selectRadio>
       </apex:pageBlockSection>

Comment: outputpanel1: <apex:outputPanel id="availSection">
         <apex:outputPanel id="innerSec">
         <apex:pageBlockSection title="Available Parent Entities" collapsible="false" columns="1" rendered="{!IF(selectedOption == 'ExistingEntity', true, false)}">
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
         </apex:outputPanel>
       </apex:outputPanel>

Comment: Outputpanel2:<apex:outputPanel id="newSection">
       <apex:outputPanel id="newSectionInner">
       <apex:pageBlockSection title="Create New Entity" collapsible="false" columns="2" rendered="{!IF(selectedOption == 'NewEntity', true, false)}">
         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem
       </apex:pageBlockSection>
       </apex:outputPanel>
       </apex:outputPanel>

Comment: I added two outputPanel sections for each sections as per some ones advise in another post but no luck.

Comment: Controller:public String getselectedOption() {
    return selectedOption;
  }
  public void setselectedOption(String updatedVal) {
    this.selectedOption = updatedVal;
  }

Comment: Please at least make an effort to help people help you.  Can you put your code in the actual question?  This is close to impossible to read.

Comment: nick, i am new to this group. Even after formatting the code, code is displayed in that way.